# Will fabric.io continue to support macOS

Tags: macos, fabric.io

We're about to publish our next macOS app and have started integrating fabric.io and it's been very helpful so far (love the drop-in support). We're still at the beginning of our integration so we could still switch to using one of the other usage tracking system.

Now that fabric.io is part of Google - I'd like to know wether they are going to continue macOS support?

Edit 11-19-18: looks like macOS support will end once fabric has been fully migrated to firebase mid 2019 -> https://get.fabric.io/roadmap (see FAQs at the bottom) - I'm disappointed.

Comment: If there is no official statement about this yet, only Fabric/Google can answer this. Ask this from them.

Comment: @TamásSengel I've updated my question to reflect the answer, it's "no", macOS will no longer be supported.